# Abnormal ips in nginx access.log

Tags: nginx

```
2a02:a447:6f7c:1:74a6:631b:6a4f:5469 - - [05/Dec/2019:01:07:25 +0100] "POST /ajaxHighscores.php?world_id=0&vocation=10&type=7&page=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 1133 "https://domain/highscores" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
188.121.4.100 - - [05/Dec/2019:01:07:25 +0100] "GET /player/layout/images/picture.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3070 "https://domain/player/search" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
```

'2a02:a447:6f7c:1:74a6:631b:6a4f:5469' why someone accessing with this kind of ip? Is it possible to add fail2ban rule for it?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with this IP address. It's just an [IPv6 address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address).

The IPv6 is the next-generation IP protocol allowing for more IP addresses, and its adoption rate steadily [grows](https://www.google.com/intl/en/ipv6/statistics.html#tab=ipv6-adoption).

You should not block those unless specific addresses are doing a malicious activity.

Just treat them same as IPv4.